# Broken theme, template is missing

Tags: theme-development, templates, css

I'm beginning to learn theme creation, so I have created a simple theme:

```
my_theme
    css
        style.css
    images
        logo.png
    index.php
```

Why does it appear as a broken theme ("missing template") in WordPress?

`style.css` :

```
/*
Theme Name: Kaoka
Description: Theme personnalise pour le site Kaoka
Version: 0.1
Author: Agence Nature / Brunet Production
*/
* {
    border:0px;
}
```

`index.php` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mon premier tutoriel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bienvenue sur le site <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
    <p><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS file should be in the root of your theme, not in a folder

Edit: in case I wasn't clear, you need to take the CSS file out of the css folder, and place in the my_theme folder itself. It should be on the same depth as index.php

Comment: Yes ! it was simple as that ! But it's weird, as my css file was detected. The Theme tabs in BO was displaying the info I put in the header... Anyway, thanks a lot. I currently don't have enough reputation to remove the -1, but your answer deserve it. I don't understand why it was downgraded